# How to create chapter based YouTube playlist like "The Coding Train"?

Tags: youtube

I'm not sure to ask here this question, but i really want to know. How can i create this kind of playlist on YouTube ?

[image: Pic of Playlist]

This is the screenshot of The Coding Train YouTube channel's playlist. If you want to see at live, here is the link [Code! Programming with p5.js](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6Zy51Q-x9tMWIv9cueOFTFA)